# When Using Nitro Add and it gets to the choose database engine question, the choices arent there and typing in doesn't work

Tags: database, nitro

I'm totally new at craft cms and nitro and I'm having trouble adding a new site. When I get to the part where it asks you which database engine to use there's no options there to choose from and typing in the database info doesn't work either. [image]

So I'm basically stuck at this point. I'm on mac os catalina. I think I installed everything correctly (nitro and craft itself) but I'm honestly not 100% sure so if there's a way of checking that could someone tell me? I'm about to give up on this so if anyone could help at all that would be amazing. Pretty new to web development so please be kind : ) Thanks!

Comment: Do you see a _Databases_ section with one (or more) engines listed when you run `nitro context`?

Comment: Yeah when i do that they are there like this: Databases:
  engine:  mysql 8.0  hostname: mysql-8.0-3306.database.nitro
  username:  nitro  password: nitro
  port:  3306
  ---
  engine:  postgres 13  hostname: postgres-13-5432.database.nitro
  username:  nitro  password: nitro
  port:  5432
  ---  So I guess they are there but its not seeing them for some reason when i try to add a site? Thanks

Comment: If you open Docker Desktop, are all of the containers you see on the first page running and green? Or do you see red/grey ones?